# Cannot run MVC4 project if not using standard output directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My project structure looks like this:

- src
  -- class library 1
  -- class library 2
  -- web project
- bin
  -- debug
  -- release

The default output directory for an MVC4 web project is `.\Bin\` (i.e. within the web project's directory), but I change it to something like `..\bin\debug\` or `..\bin\release\` to fit my above project structure. It compiles fine and the binaries go to the correct places.

But when I run the project it complains that `Could not load type Myproject.MvcApplication`, whereas if I don't make the above changes then it works.

*How do I control the location for the binaries?* I want the output directory to be completely separate from the source directories - it's easier to deploy and more secure because I don't have a mixture of source and binaries in one place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer, you can't.  It has nothing to do with Visual Studio or even .NET, it's an IIS restriction.

The reason is that IIS expects the bin directory to be directly under the web site folder location.  This is a security mechanism that you cannot bypass.  It's purpose is to prevent a compromised web site from "escaping" from the bounds of the root directly of the site.

Why would you even WANT to do this?

Comment: Because I use msbuild, and I deploy everything from my msbuild's output bin directory. And because I want the source separate from the binaries so I never accidentally give the files to someone who shouldn't have them.

Comment: I don't see this as a problem. Maybe what I must do is figure out how, for convenience, when I click the run/debug button, it runs the website from my msbuild's bin directory and not from the project's bin directory. Can I make IIS Express do that?

Comment: @BobbyB - You can't run your website from the Bin directory, it needs access to files, like view files, javascript, images, etc... those all must be below the root directory, so if you make your bin directory your root directory, then you would have to copy your entire website structure within the bin directory.  You're not really making sense.

Comment: There is sense in it - msbuild automatically copies all those files to the output directory, so that it contains absolutely everything needed in order to deploy. This is done in a continuous integration system and it all works. I just cannot get it to run with IIS Express locally for the reason you explained (because it assumes the project directory is the root).

Comment: @BobbyB - No, there is no sense to it.  A Bin directory contains only assemblies, and not support content files.  What's more, you can't have both a debug and release folder under bin, that would create duplicate assemblies that IIS choke on because they would conflict with each other.  Finally, you want to debug from the build output location that doesn't contain your source files?  That's pointless.  You seem to be confusing deployment targets with build output directories.

Comment: What I called "bin" then has a different meaning, but it does make sense, and we use it for a large system- call it output directory if you wish. In that directory there is an actual "bin" directory in which there is nothing other than DLLs (and debugging is not done in there anyway, only on the dev machine). The logic behind our project structure is not in question, whether I can make IIS Express load a website from where I want (rather than from the project folder in VS) is the question. I guess it cannot be done.

Comment: @Erik Funkenbusch it sounds like there are good technical reasons not to have build-config specific output directories (which many of us were unaware of but) but this is an organized (and the default) way to setup other projects in the solution.  it seemed natural to me to do this, so that differing config files and binaries could be segregated from each other.  it would be nice if the project properties wizard in VS prevented you from changing the dir...

Answer (score 2):

I hit this as well, it is unexpected and confusing given that separation of debug and release binaries is standard practice and MVC has an output folder setting which makes it tempting to do so. It is possible to do this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13263992/746754), but it is a bit ugly.

It seems that there is a conflict between adhering to the expectations of IIS and the need to keep debug and release separate and clearly labelled. I think that there is a need for both that the current solution doesn't satisfy very well. Debug and release are build time considerations, adhering to IIS is package/deploy time and the two have become confused.